# expected expression in conditional

Tags: swift, guard-statement

I have written the following function and am getting the following error in the guard statement.

> expected expression in conditional

```
func containsNearbyDuplicate(_ nums: [Int], _ k: Int) -> Bool {

    // form a dictionary key is the number, value is the index
    var numDict = [Int : Int]()
    for (i,num) in nums.enumerated()
    {
        guard let index = numDict[num] , where i - index <= k else
        {
            numDict [num] = i
            continue
        }
        return true
    }

    return false

}
```

Comment: What's the `where` doing into the `guard`?

Comment: @Cristik if `index` is not null, then checking `where `

Comment: Try removing the keyword, see what happens :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `where` keyword adds another expression to the first expression of the actual `guard` statement. Instead you can separate both expressions by a comma and remove the `where` keyword.

*Why is that?*

In Swift you can enumerate multiple expressions separated by commas in one `if` or `guard` statement like so:

```
if a == b, c == d {}
guard a == b, c == d else {}
```

This is similar to the `&&` operator. The difference is that the comma version allows *unwrapping of optionals* like so:

```
if let nonOptional = optional, let anotherNonOptional = anotherOptional {}
guard let nonOptional = optional, let anotherNonOptional = anotherOptional else {}
```

*Why is the Internet showing code samples where `if` and `guard` are used together with `where`?*

That's because in older Swift versions it was possible to use `where` together with `if` and `guard`. But then this was removed because `where` was meant to add an expression to a non-expression statement like `for-in` or as a constraint for `class` and `struct` definitions.

Comment: Proposal that removed `where` from conditional clauses: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0099-conditionclauses.md